GeneXus trial failed login
i'm really new to Genexus and currently following the genexus core course on the official website,
However when i tried to login to build the application, this error appeared enter image description here
Maybe it has something to do with their server but i'm not sure
Does anyone know what happened and how to fix it?

genexus cloud services are failing in recent days, you could run locally on your pc
